# How to properly use Stream's iterate and takeWhile constructs?

Tags: scala, stream

In Scala 2.12.x I have the following example but it doesn't produce the expected result:

```
val result = Stream.iterate(0)(_ + 10).takeWhile(_ < 100)
println(result)

// outputs:
// Stream(0, ?)

// while I expected:
// Stream(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, ?)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It did work, remember a `Stream` is **lazy**, thus it had not done anything yet. You can cast it to a `List` _(result.toList)_ or use a `foreach(println)` to see the result.

Comment: Ah yes! that was it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stream won't be materialized until you convert it to non-lazy colection:

```
Stream.iterate(0)(_ + 10).takeWhile(_ < 100).toList
```